# Using New Relic end-user monitoring with a Sencha Ext JS 4 application

Tags: web-applications, extjs, extjs4, newrelic

I'm planning on building my first application with Ext JS 4 and I'm curious if the New Relic application performance monitoring tool would be useful for end-user browser performance monitoring? My only experience with New Relic was building an application with the CodeIgniter PHP framework and HTML views.

Does anyone have any experience trying this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at New Relic on the engineering team.

Of course, it depends on what you want to measure. New Relic is good if you want the actual times experienced by your users. It also now captures samples of poorly performing requests.

We use it every day at New Relic. And a large portion of our 14,000 customers do as well. But it does depend on your needs.

For example: do you want to monitor server time too? (New Relic does that) Do you want more customization? (New Relic isn't infinitely customizable -- the aim is to give you a curated useful experience, not just throw data at you). There are other tools out there that have a different focus, but I'd encourage you to give it a try. It doesn't take more than a few minutes to install, so try it and let us know what you think!